# How to list all sympy symbols?

Tags: python, sympy

I am programming a little calculator using ipython console and sympy.
The setup is

```
import sympy
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
f = (x+2)**2
g = lambda y: y+3
```

It would be nice to see which symbols have already been defined in sympy.
How do I get a list of all sympy symbols? i.e. a list containing `x`, `y`, `z` and `f` but not `g`, as `g` is an ordinary python lambda.

I am looking for something like `vars()` or `globals`, but containing only `sympy` related definitions.

Comment: If you want to also get `f` then there is no way to do this.

Comment: Do you know a way to get `x`, `y`, `z` at least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
>>> b4 = set(dir())  # everything before SymPy work started
>>> ...
>>> from sympy import Basic
>>> [i for i in dir() if not i.startswith("_") and i not in b4 and
...     isinstance(globals()[i], Basic)]
```

`Basic` could be replaced with `Expr` if you wanted only symbols that pointed to `Expr`

Comment: Thanks! I will go for `[i for i in dir() if str(globals()[i].__class__).startswith("<class 'sympy.")]`

Comment: Better yet `[i for i in dir() if isinstance(globals()[i], Basic) and not i.startswith("_")]`